# Multiple Airport configuration issue

Tags: wifi, airport

I am having trouble with my 5 Airport devices. I have one Airport Extreme connected to the internet and four other Airport devices. The configuration I would like is the following:

[image: Ideal configuration for Wifi]

Invariably what happens is that the system reconfigures itself into the following:

[image: Actual configuration]

The problem with thi configuration is that "upstairs" cannot seem to work with the DHCP server in "closet", therefore anything connected to it is unable to talk to anything else.

So how can I force the ideal configuration, or how can I get DHCP to work for the whole network?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, I recommend reading Apple's guide on using multiple Wi-Fi base stations on a single network: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202056